# Bandwidth consumption between Vultr Object Storage and Cloud Compute?

Tags: vultr

Does transferring data from Vultr Object Storage to Cloud Compute consume bandwidth?
Also, please let me know if there are any documents regarding this matter.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to Vultr's documentation ([Vultr Object Storage](https://www.vultr.com/docs/vultr-object-storage/)), network between compute and object storage consumes bandwidth.

> #### How does Object Storage billing work?
>
> Please see our pricing page for up-to-date infoarmation. Data transfer between Vultr Object Storage and Vultr VPS instances traverses the public internet and incurs standard bandwidth charges.